# not able to use melt function to plot replicated data using ggplot

Tags: r

I am trying to plot the file mentioned below. I have five replicates for each sample. Each sample has eight values. The header for these eight values are:

```
mi_centereA1,mi_centereB1,ga_centere 1,ps_centereA1,ps_centereB1,sa_centere 1,il_centereA1,il_centereB1
```

the next replicate has the same header except that it has number instead of 1 as:

```
mi_centereA2,mi_centereB2,ga_centere 2,ps_centereA2,ps_centereB2,sa_centere 2,il_centereA2,il_centereB2
```

so on and so forth for five replicates...

sample-rep1-5.csv

```
win,mi_centereA1,mi_centereB1,ga_centere 1,ps_centereA1,ps_centereB1,sa_centere 1,il_centereA1,il_centereB1,mi_centereA2,mi_centereB2,ga_centere 2,ps_centereA2,ps_centereB2,sa_centere 2,il_centereA2,il_centereB2,mi_centereA3,mi_centereB3,ga_centere 3,ps_centereA3,ps_centereB3,sa_centere 3,il_centereA3,il_centereB3,mi_centereA4,mi_centereB4,ga_centere 4,ps_centereA4,ps_centereB4,sa_centere 4,il_centereA4,il_centereB4,mi_centereA5,mi_centereB5,ga_centere 5,ps_centereA5,ps_centereB5,sa_centere 5,il_centereA5,il_centereB5
1,0.451,0.447,0.394,0.441,0.427,0.409,0.410,0.410,0.438,0.436,0.394,0.434,0.422,0.396,0.408,0.412,0.461,0.456,0.379,0.441,0.432,0.400,0.410,0.413,0.454,0.450,0.395,0.434,0.424,0.395,0.398,0.404,0.449,0.451,0.403,0.432,0.419,0.441,0.404,0.409
2,0.439,0.437,0.375,0.429,0.410,0.394,0.398,0.410,0.424,0.419,0.377,0.422,0.405,0.380,0.393,0.409,0.450,0.444,0.365,0.428,0.410,0.379,0.396,0.411,0.441,0.438,0.374,0.425,0.402,0.379,0.388,0.403,0.435,0.441,0.383,0.420,0.403,0.422,0.395,0.407
3,0.447,0.421,0.362,0.423,0.399,0.392,0.385,0.397,0.432,0.407,0.368,0.419,0.399,0.382,0.384,0.397,0.452,0.426,0.351,0.421,0.404,0.384,0.389,0.402,0.445,0.422,0.366,0.419,0.391,0.379,0.375,0.389,0.442,0.423,0.373,0.418,0.395,0.426,0.383,0.399
4,0.431,0.417,0.342,0.411,0.391,0.370,0.377,0.375,0.416,0.398,0.346,0.411,0.388,0.362,0.378,0.371,0.435,0.417,0.332,0.413,0.395,0.365,0.384,0.384,0.430,0.412,0.344,0.411,0.383,0.363,0.367,0.368,0.428,0.415,0.353,0.406,0.388,0.411,0.376,0.376
5,0.422,0.403,0.329,0.406,0.391,0.371,0.370,0.372,0.403,0.382,0.338,0.411,0.387,0.361,0.363,0.366,0.422,0.404,0.322,0.412,0.396,0.367,0.374,0.376,0.428,0.395,0.332,0.407,0.381,0.366,0.357,0.366,0.420,0.398,0.339,0.405,0.388,0.415,0.362,0.370
```

I am trying to plot my data using ggplot. I want to plot all my reps in one plot and have my data plotted as five reps each of mi_centereA, mi_centereB ,ga_centere , ps_centereA ,ps_centereB ,sa_centere , il_centereA, il_centereB

I used the following code:

```
    library(ggplot2)
        library('data.table')
        df <- read.csv("sample-rep1-5.csv")
        vals <- paste0(rep(c("mi_centereA","mi_centereB","ga_centere ","ps_centereA","ps_centereB","sa_centere ","il_centereA","il_centereB"), times = 5), rep(1:5, each = 8))
       vals

[1] "mi_centereA1" "mi_centereB1" "ga_centere 1" "ps_centereA1" "ps_centereB1"
 [6] "sa_centere 1" "il_centereA1" "il_centereB1" "mi_centereA2" "mi_centereB2"
[11] "ga_centere 2" "ps_centereA2" "ps_centereB2" "sa_centere 2" "il_centereA2"
[16] "il_centereB2" "mi_centereA3" "mi_centereB3" "ga_centere 3" "ps_centereA3"
[21] "ps_centereB3" "sa_centere 3" "il_centereA3" "il_centereB3" "mi_centereA4"
[26] "mi_centereB4" "ga_centere 4" "ps_centereA4" "ps_centereB4" "sa_centere 4"
[31] "il_centereA4" "il_centereB4" "mi_centereA5" "mi_centereB5" "ga_centere 5"
[36] "ps_centereA5" "ps_centereB5" "sa_centere 5" "il_centereA5" "il_centereB5"

    df <- melt(data.table(df), id.vars = "win", measure.vars = vals)
    Error in melt.data.table(data.table(df), id.vars = "win", measure.vars = vals) : One or more values in 'measure.vars' is invalid.
        df[, color_rep := substr(variable, 1, 11)]
    ggplot() +
        geom_line(data=df,aes(x=win, y=value, color = color_rep, group = variable))+
            scale_color_manual(name="reps", values = 
    c("mi_centereA"="blue","mi_centereB"="green""ga_centere"="yellow","ps_centereA"="orange,"ps_centereB"="red","sa_centere "="black","il_centereA"="purple","il_centereB"="grey"))+
        xlab("winn")+
        ylab("nums")
```

Comment: Untested but try `paste0(rep(sub("1$","",c(...),5),...)`

Comment: Basically what your doing is `paste0("mi_centereA1", '5')` which gives `"mi_centereA15"`, the 1 is included in your first vector, the 5 pasted from the second vector. Not sure what your question is.

Comment: it doesn't return any thing. when i do this: library(ggplot2)
library('data.table')
df <- read.csv("sample-rep-1-5.csv")
vals <- paste0(rep(sub("1$","",c(...),5),...)
vals

Comment: @jay.sf I am trying to plot my data using ggplot. I want to plot all my reps in one plot and have my data plotted as five reps each of mi_centereA, mi_centereB ,ga_centere , ps_centereA ,ps_centereB ,sa_centere , il_centereA, il_centereB.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73903076/edit) your question to clarify what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to make your code work which uses `tidyr::pivot_longer` instead of `melt` and `tidyr::extract` to split the strings. For the plot I mapped your `rep`s on the `linetype` aes and added a variant using faceting:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- df |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-win) |>
  tidyr::extract(name, into = c("variable", "rep"), regex = "^(.*?)(\\d+)$") |> 
  mutate(variable = gsub("\\.$", "", variable), rep = as.integer(rep))

cols <- c(
  "mi_centereA" = "blue",
  "mi_centereB" = "green",
  "ga_centere" = "yellow",
  "ps_centereA" = "orange",
  "ps_centereB" = "red",
  "sa_centere " = "black",
  "il_centereA" = "purple",
  "il_centereB" = "grey"
)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = win, y = value, color = variable, linetype = factor(rep))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols) +
  labs(color = "reps", x = "winn", y = "nums")
```

[image]

```
last_plot() +
  facet_wrap(~variable)
```

[image]